# TV wall mount problem. (Studs too far apart)

Tags: walls, television, mount

I bought a full motion wall mount to fix 49" tv to wall. Instructions for mount specify must be fixed to studs. Studs are too far apart where I want it to go. Is there a safe way to fix or should I start looking for another place to hang tv?

Answer (score 3):

The best way to deal with this problem is to first mount a suitable piece of 3/4" plywood on the wall such that it spans to studs where it can be securely attached. The TV mount can then be mounted to the plywood using suitable screws that go into properly sized pilot holes. Note that face screwing into the plywood provides an excellent and strong mount point.

You may want to paint the plywood with primer and then a color to match the wall before affixing the TV mount.

Note that if the far distance of the stud spacing is due to trying to mount the TV over a fireplace then you should totally reconsider mounting the TV there. The main issue being that the best ergonomic placement of the TV is to locate it at eye level when you are sitting in front of it. Having to look up at the TV, even if it is tilted downwards, is a pain in the neck. (literally!). There is also consideration of what heat from a fireplace may do the sensitive electronics and plastics of the TV unit.

Comment: Thanks. Should I fix so that one side of mount is attached to stud for safety?

Comment: The whole point of the answer that I posted was about having the 3/4 inch plywood large enough to be 1) larger than the TV bracket and 2) extend across at least two if not three studs 3) the plywood securely screwed into those studs with multiple strong screws at each stud and finally 4) mount the TV bracket to said plywood noting that with proper screws the plywood will be very good at holding the bracket. The bracket has plenty of holes so use more screws as opposed to less and there should be no need to try to get one end of the bracket bolted into the stud too.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I'm just so paranoid about wrecking it now I've finally bought a tv and the instructions were very clear about fixing to studs. Bunnings here I come!

Comment: It's been awhile. How did the project go, Bee?

Answer (score 1):

Simple fix...Go to your nearest Lowes and buy theses [commercial toggles](http://www.lowes.com/pd/TOGGLER-10-Pack-1-4-in-x-2-1-2-in-Toggle-Bolts/3183831)...
these are the only ones I use on Stone fireplace tv mounting but work great with sheetrock. They hold up to 280lbs per toggle. However they are expensive.

Comment: Hang it anywhere you want