# Mounting large tv to drywall

Tags: drywall, mounting, television, mount

I have a 50-inch tv weighing in at 15kg/33lbs, that I want to mount to a drywall. Ideally, I would like to be able to use a mount that can flip the tv out at a 90 degree angle. I have not been able to find the studs in the wall. I found a very helpful and informative video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MQ2O7c8BSDY). It calls for 'snap toggle bolts'.

So here is the challenge - I live in Bangkok, Thailand. And none of the hardware stores I've visited had ever seen the pictures and video I showed them of snap toggle bolts. They came back with some suggestions, the sturdiest of which I took a photo of.

[image: FITT ANCHOR HA-514 16MM IR 5 EA]

However, nobody could tell me how much weight these anchors would properly support. And of course I don't want to risk part of the wall plus my new tv coming down!

Ideally, I hope somebody recognises these things and can tell me if they'll suffice. But that might be a stretch. Instead, perhaps somebody can give me some pointers in terms of what to look for, how to judge different solutions for suitability, etc. and I'll just continue my search.

Much appreciate your help.

Comment: You will find some folks online that will claim that it is Ok to hang a TV bracket on to a sheetrock wall with just anchors into the wall. Do not do it - Especially if you want to try using the type of bracket that allows the TV to be hinged out to a 90 degree angle from the wall. You should really try to find the wall supports and then attach a load spreading piece of plywood to those supports. Then attach the TV bracket to that. http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/94055/tv-wall-mount-problem-studs-too-far-apart/94060#94060

Answer (score 2):

No... those expanding bolts aren't going to do the job, period. There are several reasons but suffice it to say your TV will find up on the floor.  Toggle bolts of some variety are the preferred way to do it... it's hard to believe that no one in a city the size of yours has them or something more suitable.  What you need is something that will spread the weight of your TV over a wide enough surface area and not be dependent on resisting withdrawal through the sheetrock, as the ones you pictured are.  You said you can't find the studs... how have you tried?  Is your home typical studs with sheetrock over?  If they are metal studs that might be why you're having so much trouble.  But don't use what you have pictured, they are not suitable.  Let me know your answers to the above and I'm sure we can figure this out.

Comment: Honestly Rob, if we can be sure you have suitable (hollow) walls and you really can't find a way to obtain suitable anchors, might be easier for me to just send you a package... might take a week or so to get there, right?

Comment: That's a very helpful offer. But I wouldn't want to trouble you. Instead, I will ask a friend who is coming to visit me to bring some over! Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: In response to your other questions .... I have no other means than to knock and listen for differences in sound. There might be metal studs. Why would that be making the detection difficult?

Comment: @RobdeJonge  (Pt.1)Metal studs are much harder to detect by the knocking method since (being hollow and much lighter) they don't change the tone nearly as much.  Even with inexpensive stud finders they can be elusive. If your walls are sheetrock, sometimes you can look very carefully and find little telltales where the screws or nails are fastened to them as a clue.  Also generally electrical boxes are mounted to them, so you can try probing carefully to each side of the box to figure out where the stud is and then by drilling, you can look for sawdust residue to see if you're hit a wood stud.

Comment: (Pt.2)  If you can find one, the other are typically at regular intervals.  I don't know what that is where you are but I'm sure a local hardware store etc does.

Comment: Would these do? https://www.bunnings.com.au/ramset-8-x-64mm-zinc-alloy-toggle-with-screw-2-pack_p2264715 ... also, the more the better for these things, right? I figured if I use 8 of these it better distributes the weight vs. when using only 2.

Comment: @RobdeJonge ... yeahhhhhhhhhhh still not what I would want to use.  This is my preferred device.
 http://www.tannerbolt.com/default.aspx?page=item+detail&itemcode=MEC%20BC&gclid=CJ_O4LXRr84CFRJZhgod-cYJ-g

4 would be perfectly adequate

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43595/discussion-between-rob-de-jonge-and-paulbinct2).