# Studs too far apart to hang tv wall mount

Tags: television, brackets

i noticed that my studs are too far apart to use the wall mount i have to hang my tv. Do they sell extension bracket arms that attach to the tv wall mounting bracket so that i may attach it to the studs?

Comment: Standard stud spacing is 16, sometimes 24 inches.  They might sell extensions, but for most people screwing a piece of plywood or a couple of 2x4s across the studs is much cheaper.  For looks can be painted to match the wall or a different colour for a design statement.

Comment: Can you perhaps use studs closer together (not extending over as wide a stretch)?

Comment: [TV wall mount problem. (Studs too far apart)](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/94055/tv-wall-mount-problem-studs-too-far-apart?rq=1) may help. (From the "Related" links on the right side of the page. Some of the other links may also help.)

Comment: all you need is two studs to mount the tv gizmo, you do not need to go all the way outside. The two studs are only 16 inch apart so the tv mount will fit on that. Do not use 2x4 they look ugly